# Enterprise Architect - Activity diagram simulation

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, activity-diagram

I'm simulating an activity diagram using dynamic simulation with python code and I have few questions regarding this topic:

let's make a simple example : Apple counter - activity diagram

```
             START

              xxx
              xxx
               │
               │
     ┌─────────▼─────────┐
     │                   │
     │                   ├──────────────────────────┐
     │    PICK A FRUIT   │                          │
     │                   │                          │
     │                   │                          │
     └─────────┬─────────┘                          │
               │                                    │
               │                                    │
               │                                    │
               │                                    │
               ▼                                    │
              xxx     FRUIT iS AN APPLE?            │
             xxxxxx                      ┌──────────┴──────────┐
          xxxxxxxxxx                     │                     │
         xxxxxxxxxxxxx  ───────────────► │   INCREMENT APPLE   │
          xxxxxxxxxxx   fruit == "apple" │       COUNTER       │
           xxxxxxxxx                     └─────────────────────┘
             xxxxx
              xxx
               │
               │
               ▼

             EXIT
```

**Question**:
I want to embed `apple_counter +=1` inside "INCREMENT APPLE COUNTER" action

I appreciate some practical examples (also in other programming languages)  in order to understand better how to use code in simulation.

Comment: I guess you will be out of luck here as well. Maybe on Sparx' forum you might get some answer from Eve. I might have the urge to look into this dreaded area in the near future but I can't promise.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is way too broad and too vague for SO. Try to boil it down to a single narrow question, with as much example code and diagrams as possible. Make it is concrete as possible.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I added a practical example. Unfortunately I can add only ascii diagrams.

Comment: You can add images as well. They will appear as a link at first, but someone with more reputation will probably quickly inline the image for you.

Comment: Also, you still have a bunch of different questions bundled into one. Make sure to only ask one question per question.

Comment: @GeertBellekens done. I'm afraid but my organization does not allow me to update screenshot online.

Comment: Until now I never used the EA simulation (probably because I thought of the head aches ahead of it). But AFAIK it runs in some internal processor in EA: kick and go, see what happens. What would be the automation part you ask about?